# Play music to caller with mute my mic on Android

Tags: android

Is it possible: Play music to caller with mute my mic so that the call can't hear my voice or sound but he can hear the music.

Answer (score 0):

> Note: You can play back the audio data only to the standard output
>   device. Currently, that is the mobile device speaker or a Bluetooth
>   headset. You cannot play sound files in the conversation audio during
>   a call.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html